# subject-verb agreement and fractions

Tags: verb-agreement

Which is correct?

Two-thirds of the food I eat are vegetables.
Two-thirds of the food I eat is vegetables.

The first one sounds right to me, but would the second be more "grammatically" correct?

Comment: This is a mass usage of 'food' and requires 'is', like 'Half the food I eat is meat.' and  'Half the food I eat is vegetables'. With a count noun usage, use 'are': 'Two-thirds of the crops attacked by the flopweevil are vegetables.'

Comment: A good way to check is to take out the fraction and see which verb fits. Going off Edwin's examples, you would say "Food is..." but not "Food are...", and you would say "Crops are..." but not "Crops is..." Adding fractions into the mix does not change this.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I think I might have said *half the food I eat is vegetable* (singular). After all we wouldn't say *half the food I eat is meats*. Or would we?

Comment: @WS2 Anna Wierzbicka, in [The Semantics of Grammar](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=f2G3RFoxk84C&pg=PA549&lpg=PA549&dq=vegetables+plural+mass+noun&source=bl&ots=5IK_7JtGVy&sig=Cbhjf4UzfU5r4V7aT6a5pLuB9sM&hl=en&sa=X&ei=juvkVJ6AL4nVauuzgZgD&ved=0CEAQ6AEwBQ#v=onepage&q=vegetables%20plural%20mass%20noun&f=false), argues that _vegetables_ is a mass noun looking plural in form rather than a plural count noun. She also looks at _oats_ (*The only cereal I don't like is oats) in this telling in-depth study.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Umm. I took a glance at that. Yes I can see that *vegetables* has both singular and plural characteristics. But I do think it would be stretching things to compare it to 'oats'. Though the latter ends in an *s*, it is really no different to *wheat* or *barley*. But I can count *vegetables* to the extent that I had three with my roast on Sunday, sprouts, parsnips and cabbage.

Comment: I can similarly count oats – Avena sativa, A. byzantina, and A. sterilis are all known. Like coffees (C. arabica, C. robusta etc). It's just that the different varieties of oats aren't as well known to most people. Saying 'We had six vegetables with the Sunday roast' is a very different usage from 'I had six potatoes ...'. There are quite a few examples of  "... eat is vegetables ...", showing the mass usage, on the internet, eg 'about 80% of what I eat is vegetables'.

Comment: I follow all that and accept what you say. But I suppose one could equally say 'vegetables are what I like best'. Anyway, my wife has the porridge ready, so I'll enquire as to 'how many oats' she thinks there are in it, and see what she says.